# Meego builld error while Creating package

Tags: qt, qt-creator, deb, meego, dpkg

I don't understand why does my project suddenly cannot run.

I tried to reupdate all the package and now I got this error.

```
Package Creation: Running command 'c:/qtsdk/madde/bin/mad dpkg-buildpackage -nc -uc -us'.
dpkg-buildpackage: set CFLAGS to default value: -g -O2
dpkg-buildpackage: set CPPFLAGS to default value: 
dpkg-buildpackage: set LDFLAGS to default value: 
dpkg-buildpackage: set FFLAGS to default value: -g -O2
dpkg-buildpackage: set CXXFLAGS to default value: -g -O2
which: pgp: unknown command
dpkg-buildpackage: source package ethnica
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 0.0.1
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by unknown <>
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture armel
/sysroots/harmattan-nokia-meego-arm-sysroot-1122-slim/sysroots/harmattan-nokia-meego-arm-sysroot-1122-slim/sysroots/harmattan-nokia-meego-arm-sysroot-1122-slim/sysroots/harmattan-nokia-meego-arm-sysroot-1122-slim/sysroots/harmattan-nokia-meego-arm-sysroot-1122-slim/sysroots/harmattan-nokia-meego-arm-sysroot-1122-slim/var/lib/dpkg/status: File or path name too long
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: Build dependencies/conflicts unsatisfied; aborting.
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: (Use -d flag to override.)
Packaging Error: Command 'c:/qtsdk/madde/bin/mad dpkg-buildpackage -nc -uc -us' failed.Exit code: 3
Error while building project ethnica (target: Harmattan)
When executing build step 'Create Debian Package'
```

I don't understand what that means,, and I can't find any answer in google.

I can't afford to reinstall Qt again because it really taking a loooooong time.. by loooong i mean fully 24 hour. help!

Answer (score 0):

Check that line:

```
/sysroots/harmattan-nokia-meego-arm-sysroot-1122-slim/sysroots/harmattan-nokia-meego-arm-sysroot-1122-slim/sysroots/harmattan-nokia-meego-arm-sysroot-1122-slim/sysroots/harmattan-nokia-meego-arm-sysroot-1122-slim/sysroots/harmattan-nokia-meego-arm-sysroot-1122-slim/sysroots/harmattan-nokia-meego-arm-sysroot-1122-slim/var/lib/dpkg/status: File or path name too long
```

I guess this (File or path name too long) is the problem and the later error is just a result of that

Comment: yeah but I don't know where should I look to solve the problem.

Comment: For some reason it builds a path that consists of 6x `/sysroots/harmattan-nokia-meego-arm-sysroot-1122-slim` but I really have no clue why it's doing that

Comment: that's it..  I don't really understand why it do this. and I don't know where are the command that create that path.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Qt Creator's packaging feature. In my experience, it is nowhere near stable. Just use Qt Creator for running/debugging your app, and turn off the packaging. When you want to make a package, use Scratchbox. (or maybe use MADDE directly.)